# How to create a clickable Edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I know a there is a lot of similar questions out there, but none of them work for me. I want to make a `EditText` that acts like a `Button`. I want it to be not editable (and no keyboard should popup). However, when I set an `onClickListener()`, the `EditText` doesn't react to my `onClick()` event. How should I do this correctly?

In my xml I disabled the `focusableInTouchMode` and I set the `clickable` to be true. My resulting `EditText` is not editable, but it doesn't response to my `onClickListener()`.

My xml of the `EditText`:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskviewer_date"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorShadow"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:hint="No Due Date"/>
```

My Code:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskviewer_date);
text.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("taskviewer", "OnClickListener called !");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: why do you want to use EditText if you dont want user to edit text. Use TextView instead?

Comment: try a OnTouchListener instead and see if that works

Comment: I want the look of the EditText for simplicity, and the I want to user to be able to edit it Later.

Comment: If you realy need to use Edittext you can try touch events or you can put a clickable framelayout over edittext with same size and get click event from that

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: So FrameLayout will do the work. Simply make its visibility Gone when you want user to be able to edit

Comment: You welcome. Will be glad if you accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onTouch events or put a clickable FrameLayout over your EditText to catch click events. Make FrameLayout's visibility Gone when you want your edittext to be editable

Answer (score 1):

Use of EditText's `setOnClickListener` will work if you set `setTextIsSelectable` to true.

**In the XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
    android:id="@+id/textInpuLayout" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_edit_text" 
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText 
    android:id="@+id/textInpuEditText" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:enabled="false" 
    android:inputType="date"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In the appropriate **fragment or the activity**:

```
mTextInpuEditText.setEnabled(true);
mTextInpuEditText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
mTextInpuEditText.setFocusable(false);
mTextInpuEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
mTextInpuEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Edit Text is clicked");
    }
});
```